# discord.js - How to randomly split messages between mentioned users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make system, that will dm mentioned users and author of the message with one of the random messages for each*. But I wonder if there is easier way then make it with *if*.

*Example:

UserNameAuthor: Test2

userNameMentioned[0]: Test4

userNameMentioned[1]: Test1

userNameMentioned[2]: Test3

(It just doesn't happen that someone has the same message as someone else)

```
const userNameAuthor = message.author;
const userNameMentioned = message.mentions.users.map(u => u);
    
let replies1 = [
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3",
    "Test4",
];

let replies2 = [
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3",
    "Test4",
];
  
let replies3 = [
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3",
    "Test4",
];

let replies4 = [
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "Test3",
    "Test4",
]; 
  
let result1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies1.length));
let result2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies2.length));
let result3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies3.length));
let result4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies4.length));

userNameAuthor.send(replies1[result1])
userNameMentioned[0].send(replies2[result2])
userNameMentioned[1].send(replies3[result3])
userNameMentioned[2].send(replies4[result4])
```

Comment: thats because you use the same index for every person. To fix this you need to get a new index for every person that you want to send it to

Comment: Thanks for warning me about the mistake, but for example userNameMentioned[0] and userNameMentioned[2] can still get same message.

Comment: So you want each user to get a random message, but no duplicate messages between all the users?

Comment: Yes. I could do it with if, but there would be a lot of those ifs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much more regulated and simplistic way to achieve your goal is by using the `Array#splice()` method that removes or replaces a preset amount of elements in your array, with the additional option of replacing them with another element (Something that is not necessary at this point).

In your code, we can form a `forEach()` iterator to iterate through the mentioned members, send them a random message, and have the same message deleted from our array.

```js
const mentioned = message.mentions.users

let replies = [
  'test1',
  'test2',
  'test3',
  'test4'
]

mentioned.forEach(user => {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length)
  user.send(replies[random])
  replies.splice(random, 1) // Removes the element from the array
})
```

Comment: Ok, and is there some way to connect mentiond users and message author?